# Faving multiple chat messages

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As some might know, we have [LoopChat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop), which often features [hilarious quotes](http://unserkaiser.com/not-code/loopchat-wordpress-quotes-collection-part-1/). All those were extracted from our favs list - the "starred messages".

But often "starred"/faved quotes get out of context and aren't funny anymore when you don't know the whole dialogue.

**Request:** Let us bulk-"star"/fav messages, so we can as well save the best, most intelligent or just the most funny discussions in chat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use multiple stars to bookmark a conversation, use the [create new bookmark](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#permalink) feature instead.

You can find it in the upper right corner of the chat under *room*:

[image]

A [list of existing bookmarked conversations](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6/the-loop?tab=conversations) is available on the room information page.

Comment: Oha. Didn't know about that. Thanks!